# C#, Asp.net geting type returning object type WebApi 2

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api

developing Api using WebApi 2 by Microsoft i don't want to send whole model's value want to send just few just as shown in image 
i used object type for returning 
but couldn't find solution

```
if (iUser.UserId > 0)
 {
     return new object{ id = iUser.UserId, Name = iUser.UserName 
 }
```

here id and Name couldn't solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply return an anonymous object, like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, 
        new { Id = iUser.UserId, Name = iUser.UserName });
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to return anonymous type from WebApi? I've just made quick demo and it isn't working for me.